# Dynamically adding and updating fields

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to use the following partial and jQuery to allow the user to add/update/delete service records. I have an "Add service button" that's bound to a jquery function that basically retrieves the partial and appends a new set of service record fields to the existing service(s) listing.

//Jquery function to add existing rows

```
$(document).on('click','#add_service', function(e){
    if (service_count > max_services)
    {
       alert('The maximum number of service records for this person has been reached'); 
    }
    else
    {
    $.get("/service_fields", function( result ) {
            // result contains whatever that request returned
             service_count++;
            $('#service_field').append(result);                    
        }, 'html');  // or 'text', 'xml', 'more'
    }
    e.preventDefault();    
});
```

Services field (partial):

```
    Service Date
    <input type="text" name="service[{{ isset($service->id) ? $service->id : ''     }}][service_date]" >

    Service Provided <select name="service[{{ isset($service->id) ? $service->id : '' }}][service_categorytype_id]" >
          <option value="1">Mentoring</option>
          <option value="2">Personal Counseling</option>
    </select>
    Comment <textarea name="{{ isset($service->id) ? $service->id : '' }}][comment]" ></textarea>

    <input type="button" name="delete_button" value="Delete Service" >
</div>
```

The problem is when it comes to editing the record with the addition of a new service record. Without an index value ($service-id) each field would end up as a separate array, similar to what's displayed below. What would be the best way to handle this? One thought i had was to give each record an incrementing index array value [0,1,2,3] and having a hidden field that contains the $service->id to use to update existing records, but I don't know if I'm over complicating things. Thanks

```
Array
(
[3] => Array
    (
        [service_date] => 02/06/2017
        [service_category_id] => 1
        [comment] => Referred to another program to help me out or something

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [service_date] => 02/02/2017
        [service_category_id] => 3
        [comment] => This record preceeds the other service
     )

[5] => Array
    (
        [service_date] => 12/22/2016
        [service_category_id] => 7
        [comment] => Another record

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [service_date] => 03/01/2017
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [service_category_id] => 10
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [comment] => Yet another record
    )

)
```

I was planning on working on the controller logic after I found a way to build the array of the service records, but here's what I have so far. I was thinking of using the service records id value from the array (either as a hidden field or by using the service records ids as index values)

I have a participants table which has a hasMany relationship to the services table

//Controller logic adding

```
public function store(Requests\StoreParticipant $request)
{ 
  foreach ($request->services as $row => $innerArray)
    {

        $service = \App\Models\Service::find($row);

        foreach ($innerArray as $innerRow => $value)
        {
            $service->$innerRow = $value;
        }

        $service->save();        

    }
}
```

//Update action

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $participant = Participant::find($id);

        foreach ($request->services as $row => $innerArray)
        {

        $service = \App\Models\Service::find($row);

            foreach ($innerArray as $innerRow => $value)
            {
                 $service->$innerRow = $value;
            }

            $service->save();        

    }
```

Comment: can you post your controller logic for adding a service?

Comment: Typically one just does `<input name="foo[]"/><input name="bar[]"/>` and then on the PHP side `$_POST["foo"][0]` will match up with `$_POST["bar"][0]`, and `$_POST["foo"][1]` will match up with `$_POST["bar"][1]`, etc.

Comment: @miken32 which elements have the same name? I see every element in the OP's code with a diff name

Comment: ahhh, I see :-D

Comment: @miken32 I used that technique to initially save the data. If there isn't any $service data present the field names will just end up as service[][service_date], service[][service_category_id], service[][comment] for each record. The problem is when i send the $service data back to the form. The rows end up being represented by whatever the service record primary key is for the index. ex service[5][service_date], etc, but creating a new service record that lacks an index or something to bind them together, ends up creating separate areas for each field.

Comment: Yeah I would be looking at something like `service_date[]` for element names. It's not as neat for processing, but it's much easier when creating the elements.

Comment: @Paras, Sorry about the long field names, it's basically testing if a service database record exists ($service) so that i can insert it's primary key in it if not it leaves it blank.

Comment: @miken32. I did try that initially, but the problem comes in when I have to edit the data again and add additional records. Once the form is resubmitted all the field elements end up in separate arrays as seen above. The new service record I submitted in the form got split up into additional arrays, hence the idea of just using an iterator to increment the index value for each record service[1][service_date], service[2][service_date], etc. with a hidden field that contains the service record primary key so that I can update the correct record, but it might be problematic keep track of it.

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend your HTML look like this:

```
Service Date
<input type="text" name="date[]"/>

Service Provided
<select name="categorytype_id[]">
      <option value="1">Mentoring</option>
      <option value="2">Personal Counseling</option>
</select>
Comment <textarea name="comment[]" ></textarea>

<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value={{ $service->id }}"/>
<input type="button" name="delete_button" value="Delete Service" >
```

Have your Javascript produce the same elements, but replace the PHP value `$service->id` with "new".

When you process the POST request, you'll get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-01-01
            [1] => 2017-02-02
            [2] => 2017-03-03
        )

    [categorytype_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => existing
            [1] => another existing
            [2] => new
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => new
        )

)
```

Anytime you see an ID of "new" you'll know you're processing a new record.

Comment: Thanks. This will help me move forward to other parts of my app. Much appreciated!